# SQL query not executing in java application

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I'm using JDBC for the first time and having a tough time at it. This is a code snippet that is giving me error:

```
//STEP 4: Execute a query
System.out.println("Creating statement...");
String sql;
sql = "SELECT * FROM user where username=? and password=?";
stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
//Bind values into the parameters.
stmt.setString(1, value1);  // This would set username
stmt.setString(2, value2); // This would set password
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

I'm getting the following error in NetBeans:

> "`jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException`: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`? and password=?`' at line 1"

There is a long list after this but I think this is the thing which is causing me problems. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already have set the `SQL` for the statement and the parameters are bound.

Hence, you need not set the `SQL` again for the same statement. Otherwise it is an invalid statement and and exception is thrown.

**Change**:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

**To**:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```